# I suddenly can't open MongoDB Compass application

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I using MongoDBCompass to manage my database which I have not uploaded into any online platform. Everything works find until 1 hours ago, I suddenly can't open MongoDBCompass application. I don't delete or change anything. I checked the file MongoDBCompass.exe is still located path C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass.

I am using Window 10 Home. I saved many many data on this application so I think re-install is not the best way. I would appreciate any advice for what should I do so I can open without losing any data, or at least retrieve the old data then I can install MongoDB Compass again.

Comment: Re-installing (or removing) Compass wont delete data in the database. MongoDB database server _and_ Compass are two different software programs. You connect and access database data from Compass.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I re-install and it works now, no any data lost.